# Returning strings in C. Why is this working?

Tags: c, string, memory, parameter-passing

Sorry if something similar has been posted here already, but I couldn't really find it.

I have the following code and, even though I would say this is not correct, I receive the right answer.

```
char *selectStr(int index){
    char *str[] = {
        "hello",
        "hola",
        "epa",
        "alright",
    };
    return str[index];
}

int main() {
    printf("String: %s\n", selectStr(2));
    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody tell me why this actually works? The way I see it: an array of strings `str` is a local variable inside the selectStr function. This function returns a string contained inside this array. But since this array of strings `str` is a local variable, it should be cleaned from memory after it returns (right?), so I was expecting to get some sort of a memory access error.

Should I consider myself lucky that this code works (i.e. is this an undefined behavior?) or this is actually a good way of doing things (in this case, why)?

My guess is that the pointer to the array `str` gets cleaned after the function returns, but not the actual content that it points to, which stays in memory until something else writes on it. I would really appreciate if somebody could confirm that, or else, tell me what is actually going on.

Thanks in advance!

PS: The way I would do it is to pass a buffer as a parameter, but I'm just curious to know why, surprisingly --at least for me--, this actually works.

Comment: The array is local. But the literals aren't. You're returning the literals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anybody tell me why this actually works?

You're assuming this is undefined behavior and UB doesn't mean "your code will crash or fail in obvious ways", it means that anything can happen.

In this case you could envision the stack space used to store the local may not have been reused yet and may still contain the original value. It will probably fail some point down the road, but you cannot *expect* it to fail in an obvious way.

However, you're not invoking UB here as you're returning a pointer to a string literal which is allocated statically (and likely to be stored in readonly memory, so you really should be returning a `const char*`).  The *array* is local; the *strings* are not.

> PS: The way I would do it is to pass a buffer as a parameter...

You could also make the array static within the function.  Whether or not that's a good idea depends on your overall design.

Comment: Making the array `static` (or even better `static const`) would get rid of the undefined behaviour. `const` would be better as it would prevent someone messing with the strings your function returns.

Comment: @Will: I mentioned a static array at the bottom, but in this case, there is no UB.  The strings are not local to the function, a special case.

Comment: No, I suppose they aren't. Still, if you are defining the constants as part of the function it would be best to use const. Otherwise returning a copy with `strdup()` might be a good idea. You never know what kind of bugs will be awoken.

Comment: @will: Oh yeah, I don't disagree there.  The return type should obviously be `const char*` or return a copy, the array should be static as well.

Answer (score 2):

String constants, such as "anything", are not stored on the stack. Your stack (in selectStr()) contains an array of pointers, and you are returning a pointer, not the address of a pointer on the stack. Your pointer will be valid at all times in this case.

Comment: There's no concept of a stack, or readonly memory in C. So, this answer is invalid.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I agree that "automatic storage duration" would be a better way to put it, but c'mon; in reality a stack is used for locals by every C compiler I've ever used.

Comment: The function certainly has a stack, and on that stack is an array of pointers. Those pointers point to read only memory, so in essence you're agreeing with my answer but in a strange manner.

Comment: @mahH No, a stack is an implementation detail commonly used to implement a storage mechanism for variables with automatic storage duration.  The C specification does not mandate the use of a stack (or any other) structure, only that the semantics defined by the language remain true.  Richard is correct, if somewhat pedantic.

Comment: @Ed - if I create a file with only the selectStr() function and pass it through `gcc -S`, the disassembly shows a stack with 16 bytes; 4 bytes per pointer.

Comment: @mah just because GCC uses a stack as it's implementation doesn't mean it's required to.

Comment: Wow, is this argument night? required to or not, the stack is there, and yet you claim its not and you claim my answer is invalid. You've just been proven wrong, it's time to stop arguing.

Comment: @mah: And GCC would be an "implementation" or the C standard.  It's an important distinction. I agree that it's a bit pedantic, but Richard is correct, and you would do better to speak in terms of the language itself, especially when answering a question like this.

Comment: Besides, your answer is wrong.  If this were an `int[]` it would indeed be UB.  It is not because these strings are stored in readonly memory.  It has nothing to do with *"and you are returning a pointer, not the address of a pointer on the stack*" as you say.  If I did; `int *foo() { int x[1, 2, 3]; return &x[1]; }` that would be bad, yet your answer says it would be ok.

Comment: And yet a disassembly of an implementation demonstrates otherwise. If you care to run that exercise on another implementation I'm happy to listen to your results whichever way they go, but in the only implementation examined in the course of this question thus far, my answer is in agreement. As to "if it were an int[]"... if it were an int[] it would be a different question. Even as a char[], if he were changing the values to automatic memory it would be undefined -- but he is not doing any of that in the question he asked and the question I answered.

Comment: My answer does not in any way, shape or form indicate that returning the address of an int element would be ok. My answer very clearly states that because he is returning the pointer to something which is not on the stack it is ok.

Comment: I suppose I did miss that first sentence eh?  NVM on that then, sorry.  Still, I don't understand why you continue to argue.  Is it a technicality and are all C implementations likely to use a stack?  Yes.  Is Richard correct?  Yes.

Comment: You would be more correct to have said *"String constants, such as "anything", are not stored with automatic storage duration, they are allocated statically (and any attempt to modify them results in UB)"*

Answer (score 2):

This code is correct.

```
char *str[] = {
    "hello",
    "hola",
    "epa",
    "alright",
};
```

This does *not* create an array of strings.

It creates an array of *pointers to strings*.  The strings themselves are have static storage duration.  The array of pointers has automatic storage duration.  When the function returns, the array of pointers becomes off limits, but the strings still exist.

```
return str[index];
```

This dereferences the array to retrieve a pointer to one of the strings, and that pointer is returned.  `str` goes out of scope, but the pointer is still pointing to a string in static storage.

There's no harm in marking `str` as `static`.  The optimizer may already be doing so.  So you could write:

```
static char *str[] = {
    "hello",
    "hola",
    "epa",
    "alright",
};
```

If that makes you more comfortable.

Comment: I would also make those `char *` be `const`.

Comment: *"It creates an array of pointers to strings."* - Eh... a string in C is an array of characters or a pointer to a series of characters terminated by a NULL character.  So really, it is an array of strings, and an array of pointers to `char`.  A pointer to a string would be a `char**` or something equivalent.  Just a nitpick.

Comment: @EdS.: No, the term string is defined to be only the null-terminated sequence of characters. The pointer to this array is always a "pointer to a string". See 7.1.1.1 in the standard.

Comment: @EdS.: You are correct, but it's a detail that was irrelevant to the explanation, and I didn't want to confuse from the relevant detail that the pointers are distinct from the character storage.

Comment: Well, thinking about it some more, I can accept your explanation as well.  It is an array of pointers to char.  If I think of a string as a collection of characters, then it is indeed an array of pointers to strings.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I consider myself lucky that this code works (i.e. is this an
>   undefined behavior?) or this is actually a good way of doing things
>   (in this case, why)?

Probably =)  Although, from the arguments you've kicked up it's hard to tell.  For all intents and purposes, it may work for technical reasons but is not a good idea.

I would make the array static inside the function, but if that still upsets people here, why not just increase the scope?

```
static const char *str[] = {
    "hello",
    "hola",
    "epa",
    "alright"
};

const char *selectStr(int index){
    return str[index];
}
```

Program design considerations regarding globals don't really come into it when you've got this function in the same file as `main`...  If you split this off into a module, you'd make that array private to the source file and export the `selectStr` function.  No worries.

Only adjustment I'd make is to name the array something more obviously-global than `str`.

Comment: Personally I would prefer the scope to be as narrow as possible.  It's not UB though.  Making the array static is better as it clearly conveys intent, but both methods are valid.

Comment: ..."in the case of string literals" I should have added.